# NSFetchedResultController complex sort case

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have following data model:

```
[Agency] <--->> [AgencyRating] <<---> [RatingType]
```

There are numbers of `rating types` (ex. overall, branding, design, programming, etc). Each `agency` can have all these rating types (ex. `agency` FooBar has 1050 points in design and 700 points in branding).

Tables structures:

`Agency`: name:string
`RatingType`: name:string
`AgencyRating`: agency_ref: relationship to `agency`, ratingType_ref: relationship to `rating type`, value: Integer.

I have split view controller. Left side contains available `rating types`. When user picks any rating type, I'd like to show sorted by rating value agencies on the right side.

I'd like to achieve it with `NSFetchedResultController`. I understand how to get rating values to display it in cells, but I don't understand how to make a sort descriptor.

Currently I have:

Controller:

```
_contentFetchController = [Agency MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES] sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

Cell:

```
- (void) configureForAgency:(Agency *) agency ratingType:(RatingType *) ratingType forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) path {
    self.positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (int)path.row + 1];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:agency.logoPath];
    if (image) {
        self.logoImageView.image = image;
    }

    self.nameLabel.text = agency.name;

    // HERE IS VALUE OF RATING
    self.ratingValueLabel.text = [[agency ratingForRatingType:ratingType] stringValue];
}
```

As you can see: I sort by name, but I need to sort by rating value, based on selected rating type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you need to fetch `Agencies`, that have an associated `AgencyRating` with a selected rating type and sort everything by rating value.

I assume that rating type is `ratingType`, rating value is `ratingValue` and `AgencyRating` association is `agencyRatings`. I also assume that each agency can have only one agency rating of each rating type (if not, you will have to sort by the SUM of all agency ratings of selected type).

Judging by the `MR_` prefix, I guess you are using MagicalRecord, which I'm not familiar with, but here's how you can do that with plain `NSFetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController`.

First you will need to set up a `NSFetchRequest`:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Agency"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY agencyRatings.ratingType = %@", ratingType];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"agencyRatings.ratingValue" ascending:YES] ];
```

Then you can set up the `NSFetchedResultsController` as you would normally do providing it with the `fetchRequest` you just created.

Every time the user changes the `ratingType` you will need to change the `fetchRequest`'s `predicate` and call `performFetch` on the `fetchedResultsController`.

I guess you need to adjust this a little bit to fit your case, but the idea is to to have a predicate and a sort descriptor that are pointing to a related table.

Comment: won't work, as `sortDescriptorWithKey:@"agencyRatings.ratingValue"` will generate: `to-many key not allowed here`

Comment: As far as I understand there is only one solutions: use tableView with  array as a data source and populate that array with raw sql query. But I hope there is another solution:)

Comment: So here's another option:

Using the `NSFetchRequest` to get all the `AngencyRatings` with a selected `ratingType` and sorted by `ratingValue`. Don't forget to set: 
    `fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[ "agency" ];`

So, when displaying a cell, you will have the `AgencyRating` model, that has a prefetched `agency`.